# Arrays enums and input

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enumerated data type for/in a class. I want to set/assign its values from inside main. My code looks like

```
class pet
{
public:

    enum species { bird,cat,dog,rat,horse };
    enum demands { food,water,companionship };
    demands demand;
    species petSpecies;



    float waterLevel = 100;
    float foodLevel = 100;
    float Happiness = 100;

    //Species are not initialized in the class and have to be initialized separately in main

    string name;

    //And a bunch of functions here and there

};
```

Inside my main function I am using vector to create a set of pets each with its own name and species. Setting a species to the pets is proving difficult.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`vector_pets[i].petSpecies = pet::horse;` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

if you declare your enum in the class you have to use the name of the class + scope

here for example

```
pet::horse
```

you can also declare your enum outside of the class

Comment: how to do the same with "cin"

Comment: what do you mean ? @SuhridMulay

Comment: I declared a variable "pet::species spe" and now the user must enter a value for that

Comment: issue solved. used an integer input from user and put it in the code as "pets[i].petSpecie = pet::species(myInput)". Though i have no idea as to why this piece of code works.

Comment: @SuhridMulay because an enum is an integer
it's just makes it more readable for you but your enum is an integer and each possible value of the enumeration is an integer

Comment: Okay so every enum is just like a nickname for what is going to be an integer value bounded by number of enums

Comment: @SuhridMulay yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141730/discussion-between-suhrid-mulay-and-rommer).